# Transform Method Input With Aspects

Tags: java, aop, transform

I have a method that takes a String as an input, and I'd like to have an aspect intercept the method execution and, upon some certain condition, modify the String and have the join point receive the new input, so it has no idea that it's been transformed.

Is this possible, or can it not be done due to security concerns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using AspectJ you can declare an around advice like this:

```
 public aspect TransformationAspect {
   pointcut transform(String s) : call(* yourMethodName(..)) && args(s);

   Object around(String s): transform(s) {
     // ... Transform String here
     return proceed(s);
   }
 }
```

The your code has to be intrumented either at compile time or at the run time using AspectJ Java agent.

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible but would depend on the AOP technology you use.

With EJB 3.x or CDI it might be something like this pseudcode:

```
Object intercept( InvocationContext context ) {

  Object[] params = context .getParameters();

  //modify the string and update the array
  //the value of i depends on the method signature (the parameter position)
  //and getting it is left for you as an excersise
  params[i] =  modify( (String)params[i] );  

  context.setParameters( params );
  return context.proceed();
}
```